# Why is SQL subquery in SELECT clause computed multiple times?

Tags: sql, subquery

```
SELECT 
    P.Name, 
    (SELECT AVG(P1.Salary)
     FROM Payroll AS P1
     WHERE P.Job = P1.Job)
FROM 
    Payroll AS P
```

The query is to compute the average salary for each person's job. Why does the subquery actually return multiple tuples instead of one number (the average salary)?

Comment: The subquery does not return multiple tuples, it only returns a single value - but it does this for each row from the table payroll.

Answer (score 0):

IT is normal,

Using it in this subquery what you are saying if for every  P.Job, compute the average salary.
You might try it this way:

```
SELECT P.Name, p1.AvgSalaries
FROM Payroll AS P
inner join
 (SELECT P1.Job, AVG(P1.Salary) as AvgSalaries
  FROM Payroll AS P1 group by P1.Job
                ) p1 
on P.Job = P1.Job
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple "Job" available in Payroll for each "Name", your query will return multiple rows per "Name". If I guess correct, you need some GROUP BY to apply as below to achieve your required output.

```
SELECT P.Name, (SELECT AVG(P1.Salary)
            FROM Payroll AS P1
            WHERE P.Job = P1.Job)
FROM Payroll AS P
GROUP BY P.Name,P.Job
```

Answer (score 0):

Because,SELECT or WHERE clause works on row by row basis.

In a query you if you see in subquery part of select you have referenced outer main query column. For each row, it may have different values producing different results at each row.

Basically **query is looking at each employee's job and finding out avg salary offered for that job** and giving it for each of the employee.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Job, AVG(P.Salary)
FROM Payroll AS P
GROUP BY P.Name,P.Job
```